# wp_signon() does not save a cookie == cant login

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'was looking for a solution, but i found nothing.

I'm trying to make AJAX login. The scipts are sending correct data and response: bad or correct login data. After succes page is reloading and ... user is still not logged in. 
I was trying to force set a cookie, but it didn;t works.

I'm using force ssl admin (if that's important).

```
function ajax_login(){
    global $user_ID;  
    if (!$user_ID) {
        // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
        check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

        // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
        $info = array();
        $info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
        $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];    
        $info['remember'] = true;

        $user_signon = wp_signon($info, true);  
        if (is_wp_error($user_signon)){
            echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Get lost.')));
        } else {
            wp_set_current_user($user_ID);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user_ID);
            echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Wait stupid, im redirecting...')));
        }
    }
    die();
}
```

Could You help me please? I don't have an idea what can be wrong. (everything looks fine before that place, data is sending corretly, var_dump($info) also return correct data).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using true parameter for secure cookie as you are you need to use https on your login page and also https on your admin ajax url and then you will get your cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Your `wp-config.php` file should also have
`define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);`.